# Conversão para tipo date PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, data, conversão-de-tipo

Olá,

Estou trabalhando com um banco de dados que tem as informações de data armazenadas em um varchar(50) como no exemplo a seguir: "2012 dezembro 2 18:37".

Preciso fazer pesquisas baseadas em intervalos de tempo. Porém, não estou tendo sucesso na conversão desse char para tipo date.
Estou tentando da seguinte forma:

```
to_date(hora, 'YYYY month DD') = '2/12/2015'::date
```

E estou recebendo o erro:

> ERROR:  invalid value "Dezembro " for "month" DETAIL:  The given value
>   did not match any of the allowed values for this field.
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: invalid value "Dezembro " for "month" SQL state: 22007 Detail:
>   The given value did not match any of the allowed values for this
>   field.

Comment: o erro certamente ocorre porque o postgreSQL não conhece Dezembro, e sim December.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pensei em duas formas para resolver seu problema:

**1- Uma unica função que dá replace no mês e coloca um número no lugar:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.ConverteMesPT (varchar)
RETURNS varchar AS
$body$
SELECT 
Replace(
    Replace(
        Replace(
            Replace(
                Replace(
                    Replace(
                        Replace(
                            Replace(
                                Replace(
                                    Replace(
                                        Replace(
                                            Replace($1,'dezembro','12')
                                            ,'novembro','11')
                                            ,'outubro','10')
                                            ,'setembro','9')
                                            ,'agosto','8')
                                            ,'julho','7')
                                            ,'junho','6')
                                            ,'maio','5')
                                            ,'abril','4')
                                            ,'março','3')
                                            ,'fevereiro','2')
                                            ,'janeiro','1')
$body$
LANGUAGE 'sql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
COST 100;
```

Exemplo:

```
select to_date(ConverteMesPT('2012 dezembro 2 18:37'::varchar),'YYYY mm DD')
```

**2- Duas funções que se encarregam de extrair somente o mês do texto, e traduzi-lo para um número correspondente.**

*Recebe o texto, e retorna o número do mês:*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.monthFromName (
  varchar
)
RETURNS int AS
$body$
SELECT Case $1
when 'janeiro'then  1 
when 'fevereiro'then 2 
when 'março'then    3 
when 'abril'then    4 
when 'maio'then     5 
when 'junho'then    6 
when 'julho'then    7 
when 'agosto'then   8 
when 'setembro'then 9 
when 'outubro'then  10
when 'novembro'then 11
when 'dezembro'then 12
else NULL
end
$body$
LANGUAGE 'sql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
COST 100;
```

*Limpa os números e pontos que tem na string para permanecer apenas o texto:*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.limparString (
  varchar
)
RETURNS varchar AS
$body$
SELECT translate($1, '0123456789: ', '')
$body$
LANGUAGE 'sql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
COST 100;
```

Por Fim, basta chamar o comando:

```
select 
to_date(
    replace('2012 dezembro 2 18:37'::varchar,
            limparString('2012 dezembro 2 18:37'),
            monthFromName(limparString('2012 dezembro 2 18:37'))::varchar),'YYYY mm DD')
```

No seu caso:

```
select 
to_date(
    replace(hora,
            limparString(hora),
            monthFromName(limparString(hora))::varchar),'YYYY mm DD')
```

Veja qual te atende melhor, e espero ter ajudado.